# Page Curl in Android

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm the beginner of Android development 
I need to know about page curl based on this youtube video   [page curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg04wfnDpiQ&spfreload=10)
how do I use this framework? 
Or how do create this framework?
I search a lot but nothing is the good resource for me 
I  really want knowledge about creating this framework

someone help Me
I really need help
Thanks

Comment: Simply follow the description and the link under the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some open source projects that can be used to achieve the Page curl feature. [This android project](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/) or this [Github Project](https://github.com/eschao/android-PageFlip) can be used to achieve the feature. The Android page curl project uses only Canvas to render a 2D curl effect. Since it does not use OpenGL, it can be implemented for any Android Version. The Github PageFlip project uses OpenGL 2.0 to produce a 3D page curl effect.